# Kinectv2 - How to remove depth color from kinect fusion explorer - wpf example c#?

Tags: c#, kinect, mesh, kinect-sdk, kinect-v2

I have a project with Kinect v2. I have downloaded kinect fusion explorer - wpf example from kinect sdk. In the example, I get a mesh like the left one in the picture. I want to get it like the right one, without colors. Does anybody have an advice to give me that can help me to figure out how to do it? I just want to remove depth colors from the stream.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyso0.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this sample, colourization of the voxels is done by multiplying a vector containing each voxel's X, Y, Z coordinate by matrix `worldToBGRTransform`.

The default matrix maps X to blue, Y to green and depth to R with some shifts on X and Y (I don't really understand that part).

To make the output grey you have to map the colours such that R G and B are set equally.

E.g. you could edit the setup of `worldToBGRTransform` as follows (`MainWindows.xaml.cs` line 2893):

```
this.worldToBGRTransform = Matrix4.Identity;
this.worldToBGRTransform.M11 = 0.5f * this.voxelsPerMeter / this.voxelsX;
this.worldToBGRTransform.M12 = 0.5f * this.voxelsPerMeter / this.voxelsX;
this.worldToBGRTransform.M13 = 0.5f * this.voxelsPerMeter / this.voxelsX;
this.worldToBGRTransform.M21 = 0.5f * this.voxelsPerMeter / this.voxelsY;
this.worldToBGRTransform.M22 = 0.5f * this.voxelsPerMeter / this.voxelsY;
this.worldToBGRTransform.M23 = 0.5f * this.voxelsPerMeter / this.voxelsY;
this.worldToBGRTransform.M31 = this.voxelsPerMeter / this.voxelsZ;
this.worldToBGRTransform.M32 = this.voxelsPerMeter / this.voxelsZ;
this.worldToBGRTransform.M33 = this.voxelsPerMeter / this.voxelsZ;
```